# Application crashed while trying to run in emulator

Tags: java, android, logcat

I was about to finish my first simple project and TaTa! I got an error while trying to run my first simple app in Genymotion Emulator.

Here is my logcat record;

```
12-29 16:34:11.665 1019-1019/com.example.recreated.wedowhatwelearn D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002
12-29 16:34:11.705 1019-1019/com.example.recreated.wedowhatwelearn D/libEGL: loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_genymotion.so
12-29 16:34:11.709 1019-1019/com.example.recreated.wedowhatwelearn D/: HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xb819c268, tid 1019
12-29 16:34:16.193 1019-1019/com.example.recreated.wedowhatwelearn D/libEGL: loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_genymotion.so
12-29 16:34:16.197 1019-1019/com.example.recreated.wedowhatwelearn D/libEGL: loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_genymotion.so
12-29 16:34:22.117 1019-1019/com.example.recreated.wedowhatwelearn W/EGL_genymotion: eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
12-29 16:34:22.133 1019-1019/com.example.recreated.wedowhatwelearn D/OpenGLRenderer: Enabling debug mode 0
12-29 16:34:22.133 1019-1019/com.example.recreated.wedowhatwelearn D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
12-29 16:34:22.133 1019-1019/com.example.recreated.wedowhatwelearn W/dalvikvm: threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xa627f288)
12-29 16:34:22.209 1019-1022/com.example.recreated.wedowhatwelearn D/dalvikvm: GC_CONCURRENT freed 202K, 4% free 8164K/8455K, paused 71ms+1ms, total 74ms
12-29 16:34:22.241 1019-1019/com.example.recreated.wedowhatwelearn E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-29 16:34:22.241 1019-1019/com.example.recreated.wedowhatwelearn E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.NullPointerException
12-29 16:34:22.241 1019-1019/com.example.recreated.wedowhatwelearn E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource(ArrayAdapter.java:392)
12-29 16:34:22.241 1019-1019/com.example.recreated.wedowhatwelearn E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getView(ArrayAdapter.java:362)
12-29 16:34:22.241 1019-1019/com.example.recreated.wedowhatwelearn E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2267)
12-29 16:34:22.241 1019-1019/com.example.recreated.wedowhatwelearn E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1769)
12-29 16:34:22.241 1019-1019/com.example.recreated.wedowhatwelearn E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:672)
12-29 16:34:22.241 1019-1019/com.example.recreated.wedowhatwelearn E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.ListView.fillFromTop(ListView.java:733)
12-29 16:34:22.241 1019-1019/com.example.recreated.wedowhatwelearn E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1622)
12-29 16:34:22.241 1019-1019/com.example.recreated.wedowhatwelearn E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:2102)
12-29 16:34:22.241 1019-1019/com.example.recreated.wedowhatwelearn E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:13754)
12-29 16:34:22.241 1019-1019/com.example.recreated.wedowhatwelearn E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4362)
12-29 16:34:22.241 1019-1019/com.example.recreated.wedowhatwelearn E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
12-29 16:34:22.241 1019-1019/com.example.recreated.wedowhatwelearn E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:13754)
12-29 16:34:22.241 1019-1019/com.example.recreated.wedowhatwelearn E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4362)
12-29 16:34:22.241 1019-1019/com.example.recreated.wedowhatwelearn E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
12-29 16:34:22.241 1019-1019/com.example.recreated.wedowhatwelearn E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:13754)
12-29 16:34:22.241 1019-1019/com.example.recreated.wedowhatwelearn E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4362)
12-29 16:34:22.241 1019-1019/com.example.recreated.wedowhatwelearn E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
12-29 16:34:22.241 1019-1019/com.example.recreated.wedowhatwelearn E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:13754)
12-29 16:34:22.241 1019-1019/com.example.recreated.wedowhatwelearn E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4362)
12-29 16:34:22.241 1019-1019/com.example.recreated.wedowhatwelearn E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onLayout(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:435)
12-29 16:34:22.241 1019-1019/com.example.recreated.wedowhatwelearn E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:13754)
12-29 16:34:22.241 1019-1019/com.example.recreated.wedowhatwelearn E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4362)
12-29 16:34:22.241 1019-1019/com.example.recreated.wedowhatwelearn E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
12-29 16:34:22.241 1019-1019/com.example.recreated.wedowhatwelearn E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:13754)
12-29 16:34:22.241 1019-1019/com.example.recreated.wedowhatwelearn E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4362)
12-29 16:34:22.241 1019-1019/com.example.recreated.wedowhatwelearn E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1649)
12-29 16:34:22.241 1019-1019/com.example.recreated.wedowhatwelearn E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1507)
12-29 16:34:22.241 1019-1019/com.example.recreated.wedowhatwelearn E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1420)
12-29 16:34:22.241 1019-1019/com.example.recreated.wedowhatwelearn E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:13754)
12-29 16:34:22.241 1019-1019/com.example.recreated.wedowhatwelearn E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4362)
12-29 16:34:22.241 1019-1019/com.example.recreated.wedowhatwelearn E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
12-29 16:34:22.241 1019-1019/com.example.recreated.wedowhatwelearn E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:13754)
12-29 16:34:22.241 1019-1019/com.example.recreated.wedowhatwelearn E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4362)
12-29 16:34:22.241 1019-1019/com.example.recreated.wedowhatwelearn E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:1866)
12-29 16:34:22.241 1019-1019/com.example.recreated.wedowhatwelearn E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1687)
12-29 16:34:22.241 1019-1019/com.example.recreated.wedowhatwelearn E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:998)
12-29 16:34:22.241 1019-1019/com.example.recreated.wedowhatwelearn E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4212)
12-29 16:34:22.241 1019-1019/com.example.recreated.wedowhatwelearn E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:725)
12-29 16:34:22.241 1019-1019/com.example.recreated.wedowhatwelearn E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:555)
12-29 16:34:22.241 1019-1019/com.example.recreated.wedowhatwelearn E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:525)
12-29 16:34:22.241 1019-1019/com.example.recreated.wedowhatwelearn E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:711)
12-29 16:34:22.241 1019-1019/com.example.recreated.wedowhatwelearn E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
12-29 16:34:22.241 1019-1019/com.example.recreated.wedowhatwelearn E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
12-29 16:34:22.241 1019-1019/com.example.recreated.wedowhatwelearn E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
12-29 16:34:22.241 1019-1019/com.example.recreated.wedowhatwelearn E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
12-29 16:34:22.241 1019-1019/com.example.recreated.wedowhatwelearn E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-29 16:34:22.241 1019-1019/com.example.recreated.wedowhatwelearn E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
12-29 16:34:22.241 1019-1019/com.example.recreated.wedowhatwelearn E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
12-29 16:34:22.241 1019-1019/com.example.recreated.wedowhatwelearn E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
12-29 16:34:22.241 1019-1019/com.example.recreated.wedowhatwelearn E/AndroidRuntime:     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-29 16:34:26.577 1019-1019/? I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 1019 SIG: 9
```

As I'm a newbie on the way; i couldn't make any deduction out of this logcat but i think a more experienced developer will be able to help me..

Edit..

Source code:

activity_main.xml

```js
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.recreated.wedowhatwelearn.MainActivity"
   tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame"/>
```

fragment_main.xml

```js
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.recreated.wedowhatwelearn.MainActivity$PlaceHolderFragment">

    <ListView android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent" android:id="@+id/listviewsorular" />


</FrameLayout>
```

sorulardburadan.xml

```js
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:id="@+id/sorularb1">

</TextView>
```

MainActivity.java

```js
package com.example.recreated.wedowhatwelearn;


import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment())
                    .commit();
        }

    }



    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

        public PlaceholderFragment(){
        }
        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
           View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
            String[] sorularArray = {

                    "Linguistics - What is the language - 26/06/2015",
                    "Methodology - What is the Metdology - 27/06/2015",
                    "SocioLinguistics - What is the language - 26/06/2015",
                    "Language - What is the Metdology - 27/06/2015",
                    "Approach - What is the language - 26/06/2015",
                    "Syllabus - What is the Metdology - 27/06/2015"

            };

            List<String> sorularıcek = new ArrayList<String>(
                    Arrays.asList(sorularArray));

            ArrayAdapter<String> mSorularAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                    getActivity(),
                    R.layout.sorularburadan,
                    R.id.listviewsorular,
                    sorularıcek);

            ListView sorulariste = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.listviewsorular);
            sorulariste.setAdapter(mSorularAdapter);


            return rootView;
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: There's something wrong when trying to create a view, make sure everything is ok with your resources (xml layouts, values)

Comment: why you stopped on emulator? Run please it also on other devices, if you have, Android Studio emulator. It's reaaly hard to say where the errror is :-/

Comment: Alright im going to add the source code.. | Edit : Added source code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key is in line 12 of your LOGCAT output. it is showing that you have a null pointer exception meaning that you are most likely trying to do an operation on a variable/property that is in fact, null.

By the looks of it this is happening in an array adapter. This could be a resource not being created/used correctly so as mentioned above check those first.

If you can't find anything there you'll want to manually debug this by setting a breakpoint in your code. Start by placing the breakpoint in the OnCreate method of each of your Java activities code. The best place to start would be in your MainActivity's OnCreate.

This is most likely in your resource file though since it seems you are trying to populate a ListView and the resource cannot be used by the default ArrayAdapter correctly.

Comment: You would actually want to place a breakpoint in your PlaceholderFragment's OnCreate now that you have posted source. Inspect each variable to see where your null is.

Comment: Thank you sir for your answer I'm sure that your answer would take a second to apply for a user that has a bit more knowledge. But as I'm a newbie could u describe a bit more explicitly what should i do? What is breakpoint in coding?

Comment: here is a short article on it - http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-studio.html

Basically debugging allows you to step though code line-by-line and will allow you to see what values are in each variable. There are plenty of articles on this and to improve your development skills it would be very wise to get familiar with debugging! A breakpoint itself is where you would like execution to pause so that you can step through each line.

Comment: Sidenote, within your code specifically I believe it is your ArrayAdapter that is causing you the grief. Maybe look at a few more examples of how it is done. You aren't the first person to have some issues with learning about these adapters :)

Comment: Thank u sir will be working on it by reading the article you have sent.